# Crontab and python script writing to file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cron, startup

Hi im running a Raspberry Pi using OSMC and a webserver on the same Pi.

Ive made a python script which gets the cpu temp, usage, memory etc.
When i execute the script using: `sudo python state.py` it works, it gets the values and writes them to a txt file.

I want the script to run on startup so i made a crontab:

```
@reboot sudo python /home/osmc/python/state.py &
```

This works, however it dosent write the CPU stats to the file, only memory and disk stats.

My python script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import commands
import time

# Return CPU temperature as a character string                                      
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    return(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))

# Return RAM information (unit=kb) in a list                                        
# Index 0: total RAM                                                                
# Index 1: used RAM                                                                 
# Index 2: free RAM                                                                 
def getRAMinfo():
    p = os.popen('free')
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i + 1
        line = p.readline()
        if i==2:
            return(line.split()[1:4])

# Return % of CPU used by user as a character string                                
def getCPUuse():
    return(str(os.popen("top -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\):/ {print $2}'").readline().strip(\
)))

# Return information about disk space as a list (unit included)                     
# Index 0: total disk space                                                         
# Index 1: used disk space                                                          
# Index 2: remaining disk space                                                     
# Index 3: percentage of disk used                                                  
def getDiskSpace():
    p = os.popen("df -h /")
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i +1
        line = p.readline()
        if i==2:
            return(line.split()[1:5])
while True:
        # CPU informatiom
        CPU_temp = getCPUtemperature()
        CPU_usage = getCPUuse()

        # RAM information
        # Output is in kb, here I convert it in Mb for readability
        RAM_stats = getRAMinfo()
        RAM_total = round(int(RAM_stats[0]) / 1000,1)
        RAM_used = round(int(RAM_stats[1]) / 1000,1)
        RAM_free = round(int(RAM_stats[2]) / 1000,1)

        # Disk information
        DISK_stats = getDiskSpace()
        DISK_total = DISK_stats[0]
        DISK_free = DISK_stats[1]
        DISK_perc = DISK_stats[3]

        starttime = time.time()

        file = open("/var/www/html/rspi_state.txt", "w")


        file.write(CPU_temp + "\n")
        file.write(CPU_usage + "\n")
        file.write(DISK_stats[1] + "\n")
        file.write(DISK_stats[0] + "\n")
        file.write(DISK_stats[3] + "\n")
        file.write(str(RAM_total) + "\n")
        file.write(str(RAM_free) + "\n")
        file.close()
        print "CPU TEMP: " + CPU_temp
        time.sleep(9.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 9.0))
```

Is there any reason why it only write some of the data to the text file? 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `os,popen` thows away `strerr` and return code so you don't handle the case where the call fails. Use one of the calls in `subprocess` that either raises an exception on failure or lets you read stderr and check return codes yourself.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. It works if i just run the script from ssh. Is the error due to using cron?

Comment: Don't `sudo` within `cron`. Just add the script to the `root`'s crontab using `sudo crontab -e`. Also, you already have the interpreter in your script, so you can add `@reboot /home/osmc/python/state.py &` to root's crontab and it should work fine.

Comment: I tried removing sudo, no difference. aswell as removing python before the path

Comment: So there is an empty line for CPU usage? Did you do what @tdelaney wrote?

Comment: Ye the CPU usage is empty. Im quite new to python. The thing is that the script writes to a text file and does not log. There should be any errors, because the script works like a charm when im running it from the terminal.

Comment: The terminal is a different environment than cron. I think a test script focused on just the broken part is a good idea. I'll post one as an answer although that is kinda cheating.

Comment: So you haven't yet tried what @tdelaney suggested? Sigh. You ask a question, someone suggests something very sensible and you don't bother to try it. Do it. Report back.

Comment: Ok, so i sorta figured it out. I created an .sh file that startet the py script. I removed the loop from the .py file and created the loop in the .sh file. I then started the bash file from a cron. Some way it worked. However, the CPU temp and CPU usage "flickers", one second it shows both, and sometime only one of the above..

I also started the bash file with "nohup ./run-job.sh".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can diagnose the problem by writing a script focused on the problem. This one will record all of the info coming back from the system calls. I think that a modified version of `my_popen` that checks for errors... or one of the error checking calls in `subprocess` is a good idea. I do a lot of system calls myself and have a complex wrapper for Popen that logs and does all sorts of fancy stuff. Run this script the same way as your regular one and see what happens:

```
import subprocess as subp

def my_popen(cmd, file):
    file.write('cmd: {}\n'.format(cmd))
    proc = subp.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    print('return code: {}\n'.format(proc.returncode))
    print('out: {}\n'.format(out))
    print('err: {}\n'.format(err))
    print('------\n')
    return out

with file = open("/var/www/html/test_state.txt", "w") as file:
    my_popen('vcgencmd measure_temp', file)
    my_popen("top -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\):/ {print $2}'", file)
```